# how to use Ajax with Python flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have written, AJAX script using Jquery. When I debug through the script, I noticed that it doesn't go through 'success' and 'error' but it exists.

Here is the JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#report-submit').click(function() {
        alert('inside click');

        $.ajax({

            url: '/admin/file/start/rerun_reports/',
            //data: $i('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                //alert(response);
                console.log("it works..................");
                console.log(response);
                $("#log-results").html(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

However, when I submit the the button, I get the data to browser without Ajax.

Here is the html code

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/file/start/rerun_reports/">
                <input name="_csrf_token" type=hidden value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="report-submit"
                    type="submit" value="submit">

            </form>
```

Here I send the data to browser

```
return render_template('tools.html', data = json.dumps(start.logdata))
```

When print the status code. I get the `403 error`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Flask-WTF for CSRF?

Comment: I have added CSRF token to html form. anything else?

Comment: If you're using Flask-WTF you can just write  `{{ form.csft_token }}`

Comment: Did you allow the method post ? @api.route("/admin/file/start/rerun_reports/", methods=[ 'POST'])

Answer (score 0):

You are posting thruogh `html submit form` and also via `AJAX`.So if you want to `POST` via `AJAX`.Change `type='button'` like

```
<input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="report-submit"
                type="submit" value="submit">
```

to

```
<input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="report-submit"
                type="button" value="submit">
```

Comment: So it is no posting via `ajax` ?

Comment: When I try to print the status code, I get NetworkError: 403 FORBIDDEN